# How can I get GLTexture from camera in order to use it in JNI?

Tags: android, opengl-es, java-native-interface, android-camera

I have tried to develop app based on OpenGLES in JNI using camera. But through the display result, I realized that camera's resolution and aspect ratio and GLTexture's resolution are different. I set both camera resolution and GLtexture to VGA(640*480).

```
public class MainRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer,
                SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener {
            ...
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

            // ///////////////////// Camera ////////////////////////////////////
            int cameraid = 0;
            int numofCamera = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < numofCamera; i++) {
                Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
                if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK/* CAMERA_FACING_FRONT */) {
                    cameraid = i;
                }
            }
            // ///////////////////// Camera ////////////////////////////////////

            mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(JNIpr.init(tWidth, tHeight)); //resolution : 640,480
            mSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);


            mCamera = Camera.open(cameraid);
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            //set camera to continually auto-focus
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

            params.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            //some more settings


            List sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            Camera.Size result = null;
            Camera.Size camSizeVGA = null;
                for (int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++){
                    result = (Size) sizes.get(i);
                    Log.i("msg", "Supported Size. Width: " + result.width + "height : " + result.height);
                    if(result.width==640 && result.height==480)
                    {
                        camSizeVGA = result;
                    }
                }


            //set camera resolution
            params.setPictureSize(camSizeVGA.width, camSizeVGA.height); 
            mCamera.setParameters(params);

            mCamera.startPreview();

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            }

        }
        @Override
        public synchronized void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            mUpdateSurfaceTexture = true;
            mView.requestRender();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (mUpdateSurfaceTexture) {
                    mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
                    mUpdateSurfaceTexture = false;
                }
            }

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            pTime = JNIpr.render(filterID); // filterID : 0

            GLES20.glFinish();
            // ////////////////////////////////////
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
       }
}
```

And in Native render(filterID) function, I set glViewPort(0,0,1920,1080) to display in full-screen on Samsung galaxy S5.

Is there any wrong line?

How can I use camera image stream with same resolutio in the jni??

Comment: The SurfaceTexture constructor takes a GLES texture name, i.e. an integer, as an argument. You don't configure SurfaceTexture's size; it takes whatever is passed to it and converts it to a GLES texture. Not really sure what the `JNIpr.init()` call does or is expected to do. Also, remember that *picture size* and *preview size* are independent.

Comment: @fadden then how can I use camera image stream with same resolutio in the jni??

Comment: The GLES texture has the same resolution as the camera image (by definition... there's no copying or manipulation on the image data). You either need to configure Camera to produce preview images with an aspect ratio that matches the display (which is not possible on all devices), or modify your display to letterbox or pillarbox the output. You're configuring the picture size, but you're not configuring the preview size, and it sounds like the preview is what's not matching.

Comment: @fadden thanks a lot :) your comment works for me